# passing nullptr to std::stoi

Tags: c++, pointers

For the stoi function documented in the below reference,

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/

```
int stoi (const string&  str, size_t* idx = 0, int base = 10);
```

It is then used as

```
int i_hex = std::stoi (str_hex,nullptr,16);
```

Here the idx is not defined as constant pointer (size_t * const idx =0), why can we pass nullptr as the arguments? Isn't nullptr a constant?

Comment: Same reason you can pass `5` to a function taking `int`.

Comment: @nanofarad `nullptr` is not itself a pointer, but it is *convertible* to a pointer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for clarifying my misconception.

Comment: You're probably confusing references and pointers and trying to apply the "You can't bind an rvalue as a non-const reference." rule to pointers, which is incorrect.

Comment: @Holt, yes, i think this might be my confusion, let me review this part again.

So for function parameter, 
1. pass by value: we define (int para), we can pass constant like 5.
2. pass by reference: we define (int &para), we can't pass constant like arg in (const int & arg). As the function might change a constant reference which is not supposed to happen
3. pass by pointer: we define (int *para), we can pass constant like nullptr. It is implicitly converted to pointer type. As it doesn't point to anything, there is no bad side effect.

Comment: @WriteBackCMO, You can also do `int* const p = &x;` and pass `p` despite it being a const pointer that points to something. It's exactly the same logic as regular `int`—pass by pointer _is_ pass by value, and the value is an address.

Comment: @chris, thanks. yes, passing constant pointer just passes the copy of the value of the pointer (address to x) to the function, it can't modify the pointer itself in the function. So even if the function tries to modify the value of the pointer, it just modifies such value of the temporary copy of hte original pointer, which has no effect on the original pointer,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`nullptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) [is not a pointer at all](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/K5cxYY). It is a [prvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue) of type [`std::nullptr_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t). But, it can be implicitly converted to *any* pointer type. Whether the pointer type is const, volatile, etc does not matter. So, the above code is fine.